# What files do I backup for frequent crashes?

Tags: xubuntu, backup, xfce

I currently run Xubuntu 19.04 on an old HP laptop. Due to overheating, the laptop crashes frequently and due to this, files occasionally get corrupted.

Files that have been corrupted:

- .zsh_history: I've fixed this and made a small script to automate this answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/957924).
- Firefox data: I now use the snap version + Firefox sync.
- Whisper menu: This is mainly why I made this post. Just yesterday, I clicked the whisper menu, and then the laptop crashed suddenly. On booting up, I find that the config has been corrupted. (Size of icons, and favorite applications have gone back to default)

Therefore, my questions are: Where are the XFCE UI settings stored, or more generally, **What are important files that are a good idea to back up?**

Comment: Many XFCE config files are located in ~/.config/xfce4/

Comment: @guiverc That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  Please post an answer, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote! **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

Many XFCE config files are located in ~/.config/xfce4/

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   ls -ltrha ~/.config/xfce4/
total 48K
drwxr-xr-x  3 guiverc guiverc  118 Nov 16  2017 xfconf
drwx------  2 guiverc guiverc    6 Nov 16  2017 xfwm4
drwxrwxr-x  3 guiverc guiverc   98 May 14  2018 src
-rw-rw-r--  1 guiverc guiverc  462 May 16  2018 xfce4-taskmanager.rc
-rw-rw-r--  1 guiverc guiverc   74 May 22  2018 helpers.rc
drwx------  2 guiverc guiverc  190 Dec 13  2018 terminal
-rw-rw-r--  1 guiverc guiverc  108 Jan 18 20:11 xfce4-screenshooter
-rw-rw-r--  1 guiverc guiverc   19 Mar 28 20:02 help.rc
drwxr-xr-x  8 guiverc guiverc 4.0K Mar 28 20:02 .
drwx------  2 guiverc guiverc 4.0K May 26 14:28 desktop
drwx------ 27 guiverc guiverc 4.0K May 26 18:58 panel
drwxr-xr-x 86 guiverc guiverc  16K Jun 16 16:17 ..
```

*originally just a comment, @Fabby suggested making it an answer*